# Divide column in to sections - Gridview

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, componentone

I have gridview which contains merged cell and columns.
I am trying to devide one cell in to separate sections but had no luck.
Basically below image show what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Currently I have the first picture structure and I want it to be like second picture. (In image I have only separated the columns in first 2 rows only, but I expect it to be in whole grid.)

Basically from column 2 and other will contain a date as heading. So I want the the difference of two days to be split in to separate sections.

eg

```
Col2(1/1/2012)         | Col3(7/1/2012)
This col will split    |
in to 6 sections (7-1) |
```

Any help is appreciate!!

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the beautiful free hand excel like squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it by merging the row data for the first row.

I have added new columns according to the date difference and for one set of date difference, I added the same column header which will merge them together.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1"**
you can build a html string in table format and bind it to the grid. do this in the code behind.

```
  sb.Append("<table style=\"width: 100%;\"> ");


for (int i = 0; i < cnt;i++)
        {
            col1="";
            col2="";
            col3="";

            String fmt= @"<tr>
                            <td style='width: 33%;' >
                                <b>{0}</b>
                            </td>
                            <td style='width: 33%;'>
                                {1}
                            </td>
                            <td style='width: 33%;' >
                                {2}
                            </td>
                        </tr>";

            col1 = row[i].col1 ;
            col2 = row[i].col2 ;
            col3 = row[i].col3 ;

            sb.AppendFormat(fmt, col1,col2,col3);
        }
        sb.Append("</table>");
```

**Option 2:**
(Or you can have a table format in gridview in aspx page)

```
<ItemTemplate>

<div class="innerTable">
 <table>
    <tr >
       <td ></td>
       <td ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: ops..sorry if you miss understood!! this not asp.net, its a winform application